# Why I get java.lang.IllegalStateException while unit-testing module that works with Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, junit, mockito, powermockito

I unit-test the class that performs some logic with Firebase. All the unit tests on that module seemed to work fine apprx. 2 weeks ago. This week I changed a lot of stuff in my app and today unit-tests, mentioned above, threw errors.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to transform class with name com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage. Reason: getSentTime ()J in com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage: inconsistent stack height -1

Unit-test:

```
    @Test
    public void onMessageReceived() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(UiTools.class);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(RemoteMessage.class);
        fcmService = spy(Whitebox.newInstance(FcmService.class));
        Service service = mock(Service.class);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(Service.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(service);
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("message", "test");
        remoteMessage = mock(RemoteMessage.class);
        PowerMockito.when(remoteMessage.getData()).thenReturn(map);
        PowerMockito.when(remoteMessage.getNotification()).thenReturn(mock(RemoteMessage.Notification.class));
        PowerMockito.doNothing().when(UiTools.class, "sendNotification", anyString(), anyString());
        fcmService.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        verify((FirebaseMessagingService)fcmService).onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    }
```

I try to mock RemoteMessage, try to spy RemoteMessage, try to use WhiteBox on RemoteMessage - but error not fixed.

When I change mock RemoteMessage to create new object

```
final HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("message", "test message");
RemoteMessage remoteMessage = new RemoteMessage.Builder("test").setData(map).build();
/* next string is DataApi_FcmServiceTest.java:97 - look on next error */
fcmService.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
```

I get new error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.Constants$MessagePayloadKeys.extractDeveloperDefinedPayload(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@21.0.1:2)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage.getData(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@21.0.1:1)
    at club.people.fitness.data_api.FcmService.onMessageReceived(FcmService.java:30)
    at club.people.fitness.data_api.DataApi_FcmServiceTest.onMessageReceived(DataApi_FcmServiceTest.java:97)
```

And this error I can't fix becouse in method getData() Firebase want to do this: `this.bundle.putString("collapse_key", var1);` but this.bundle allways null